# How to make a member function which returns a pointer to a member function?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Hello I want to declare a pointer to a member function as a member data under `private scope` and make a `getter` to get it from outside:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(){ ptr = Foo;} // for example: ok
        void Foo(){ cout << "Foo()" << endl;}
        void Bar(){ cout << "Bar()" << endl;};

        void (A::*)() GetPtrFunc() {return ptr;} // error here? 

    private:
        void (A::*ptr)(); // ok here
};
```

As you can see, `ptr` is a member of class `A` which is a pointer to member class of the same class so I cannot use it from outside so how to return it in a getter?

Comment: `void(A::*GetPtrFunc)()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there's a way to write out this declaration, you will find it less confusing to use a `typedef`:

```
    typedef void (A::*mem_func_ptr)();

    mem_func_ptr GetPtrFunc() {return ptr;}

private:
    mem_func_ptr ptr; // ok here
```

Additionally, your initialization, in the constructor, was not correct. Full, corrected example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(){ ptr = &A::Foo;}
        void Foo(){ cout << "Foo()" << endl;}
        void Bar(){ cout << "Bar()" << endl;};

        typedef void (A::*mem_func_ptr)();

        mem_func_ptr GetPtrFunc() {return ptr;} // error here?

    private:
        mem_func_ptr ptr; // ok here
};
```

Comment: the only thing @Sam : how to call that function pointed by ptr: `aObj.GetPtrFunc()()`?

Comment: `aObj.getPtrFunc()` returns a pointer to a class method. It is not a pointer to a function that you can invoke just by slapping on an extra pair of `()`. If you want to invoke it on the same object: `(aObj.*(aObj.getPtrFunc()))()`. Open your `C++` book, and read the explanation of the `.*` operator.

Comment: this works: `(aObj.*aObj.GetPtrFunc())();` is it correct?

Comment: missing parenthesis in your code: `(aObj.getPtrFunc()))()` where to add it?

Comment: `(aObj.*(aObj.getPtrFunc()))()` -- what I wrote looks right to me. Four `(`s and four `)`s. Your version's fine too. It's merely my personal preference to add explicit parenthesis. I don't always memorize the relative priority of various `C++` operators.

Answer (score 2):

You can move `GetPtrFunc` after `ptr` and declare it `decltype(ptr)`:

```
private:
     void (A::*ptr)() = &A::Foo;
public:
    decltype(ptr) GetPtrFunc() { return ptr; };
```

or (without the order constraint) just declare it `auto`, cretig goes to **@Jarod42** and **@user975989**:

```
auto GetPtrFunc() { return ptr; };
```

Comment: `auto` would be enough btw.

Comment: If you're going to go the generic route why not `auto`?